# Using ChainlinkVRF vs ChainlinkClient createRequestTo to get a random number

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am trying to get a random number from a chainlink oracle and don't know the difference between two ways of doing it. The chainlink documentation says to use a RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase to get one, but I found an alternative in chainlink truffle box.

First way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    
    uint256 public randomResult;
    
    /**
     * Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBase
     * 
     * Network: Kovan
     * Chainlink VRF Coordinator address: 0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9
     * LINK token address:                0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
     * Key Hash: 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4
     */
    constructor() 
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        )
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK (Varies by network)
    }
    
    /** 
     * Requests randomness 
     */
    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

Second way:

```
/**
   * @notice Creates a request to the specified Oracle contract address
   * @dev This function ignores the stored Oracle contract address and
   * will instead send the request to the address specified
   * @param _oracle The Oracle contract address to send the request to
   * @param _jobId The bytes32 JobID to be executed
   * @param _url The URL to fetch data from
   * @param _path The dot-delimited path to parse of the response
   * @param _times The number to multiply the result by
   */
  function createRequestTo(
    address _oracle,
    bytes32 _jobId,
    uint256 _payment
  )
    public
    onlyOwner
    returns (bytes32 requestId)
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(_jobId, address(this), this.fulfill_random.selector);
    requestId = sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, _payment);
  }
```

Can I use the second way to make chainlink requests to any oracle I want without having to interface with Consumer smart contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is the most secure way to request a random number.

The first way send a request specifically to the Chainlink VRF (Verifiable Randomness Function). The VRF provides cryptographic proof that the number was generated in a truly random way.

The second way is meant for sending and receiving generalized API data through a Chainlink node. This still requires the import of the "Chainlink Client" contract. You could find an API that sends random numbers and use this, but you wouldn't have the cryptographic proof that the Chainlink VRF provides. You can learn more about the AnyAPI feature in the [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data/).